# solvePnP: Obtaining the rotation translation matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, computer-vision, transform

I am trying to image coordinates to 3D coordinates. Using the solvePnP function (in C++)has given me 3X1 rotation matrix and 3X1 translation matrix. But isn't the [R|t] matrix supposed to be 3X4?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i.e. how to combine rotation and translation matrices into a transformation matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OpenCV documentation for [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp):

- "rvec – Output rotation vector (see Rodrigues() ) that, together with tvec , brings points from the model coordinate system to the camera coordinate system."

Following the link to [Rodrigues](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20Rodrigues(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20OutputArray%20jacobian))():

- src – Input rotation vector (3x1 or 1x3) or rotation matrix (3x3).
- dst – Output rotation matrix (3x3) or rotation vector (3x1 or 1x3), respectively.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I have successfully obtained my rotation translation matrix and thus the projection matrix. However, as shown in the documentation, how do I obtain the scaling factor 's'?' I managed to solve the matrix for a particular mapping, but that doesn't seem to work for all. Can you help here?